# How to Stop and Start a Video Object with jQuery or JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

i habe a normal video tag like this one:

```
<object id='AtriumMediaVideo' width='936' height='576' style='z-index: 1;' classid='CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95'" type='application/x-oleobject'... > <embed type='application/x-mplayer2' pluginspage='http://microsoft.com/windows/mediaplayer/en/download/' id='mediaPlayer' name='mediaPlayer' ... src='videos/movie.wmv' >
```

.wmv Object.

How can i stop or start this movie with javascript or jQuery? I have a jQuery slideUp animation and i want to start this video if it is on focus.

thx.

Comment: have a look at my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19298733/is-there-any-way-api-to-interact-with-an-object-playing-a-video/19304217?noredirect=1#19304217

Answer (score 0):

Using **jQuery** in **IE8** I found out this

```
$.each($('.object_vid'), function(k,v) {
    v.stop();
});
```

Where .object_vid is the object tag class.

Also I was using **fancybox**, so if anyone find it useful, I put that code inside the 'beforeClose' event, cause 'afterClose' event is too late for it.