# Is there any way/ API to interact with an <object> playing a video?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, video

**See my own answer, got it working!**

I am using video.js to play videos on a website which will also have to work offline, hence the usage of flash is not possible. Since video.js uses a flash fallback, I wrote my very own.

In IE8 for instance and object is created:

```
<OBJECT codeBase="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" classid=CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95 width=660 height=418 type=application/x-oleobject>
<embed src="Videos/Aktionen_Coffee-Stop/Teaser_Coffee-Stop.wmv" type="application/x-mplayer2" enabled="1" showstatusbar="1" ShowControls="1" ShowStatusBar="0" ShowDisplay="0" autostart="true" width="660" height="418" scale="tofit"></embed></OBJECT>
```

This works perfectly fine and the object renders a video player (windows media player i.e., resp. quicktime in older mac/safari versions).

Is there any way in JavaScript to make this video playing to stop, replay, fire an "ended" like event?

Edit: [even when looking at these "docs"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd564034%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - how to freakin create a Player object? How can people create such a doc? Seriously MS...

**Update**

```
var wmp = $('#wmp').get(0);

setTimeout(function() {

    console.log(wmp.Controls.currentPosition());
    wmp.Stop();
}, 2000);
```

the `wmp.stop()` will work, but `wmp.Controls` or `.controls` always throws an error. I just want to know when the video has ended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out some really weird stuff (who would have guessed, its MS).

First thing, I was always getting errors that Player.controls is not available. Maybe it has something to do with that I use the `CLASSID="CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95"` in my code rather than `CLASSID="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6"` as described in the `"docs"`. This is because using any other classid would cause the wmp not to load/play the video, so I'd have to go with that classid.

```
var player = document.getElementById("player");
```

So, no matter what I did, any of the [objects listed here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd563945%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) were not available in my player object, like `player.controls` or `player.media`, none of them.

So I tried to just log the whole player object to see what actually is there: `console.log(player)`. IE8, awesome as it is, gracefully printed this in the log: `[object]`. What a surprise, really. Debugging did not work (how could it...). So, I did a `for (a in player)` log :) IE crashes. Awesome.

Strangely, after opening a new tab, the console showed up with all the logs. I found out, and this is the strange but awesome-since-works-now part: all the properties, methods and stuff are directly put into the player var, so it's not `player.controls.currentPosition` but rather `player.currentPosition`. Booya.

This is my working code:

```
    var obj = '<object id="wmp" CLASSID="CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" TYPE="application/x-oleobject" width="' + parseInt(parsed.width) + '" height="' + (parseInt(parsed.height) + 0) + '" codebase="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/">';
..
obj += '</object>';

$('#wrapper').html(obj);

var wmp = document.getElementById("wmp");

wmp.attachEvent('playStateChange', function(a) {
    if (a == 8 || a === 0 || a === '0' || parseInt(a) === 0 || a == 'MediaEnded') {
        // check if playback has really finished
        var cpos = wmp.currentPosition,
            dur = wmp.duration;

        if (dur - cpos >= dur - 0.1 ) {
            console.log('the video has ended');
        }
    }
});
```

[This page here suggests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564085%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to use the state 8 when the video has finished playback which actually never is 8, ever. It's rather randomly 0, 2 or 3. Mostly 0.

Hope this helps anybody!

Answer (score -1):

Javascript API for WMV player to restart playback after video ended..

```
document.getElementById("Player").attachEvent("PlayStateChange",function(newState) {
         if(newState == "1") // stopped, restart playback paused at 3 seconds
        {
             document.getElementById("Player").controls.play();
             document.getElementById("Player").controls.pause();
             document.getElementById("Player").controls.currentPosition = "3";
        }
    });
```

Comment: This does work... I tested it myself. How hard must I work here?